# Convert HTML Menu Code In Blogger to SubMenu

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown, blogger, submenu

I have following Menu HTML code in Blogger. It gives Dropdown as Kubernetes and under it Kubernetes Config, Kubectl commands etc. I want to have multilevel submenu dropdown for e.g. Kubernetes under it Kubenetes config and under that if we mouse over it should go to Kuberctl commands. For e.g. I am looking for submenu which is described in youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pJBZaHrBkE&ab_channel=CMManjunath

Can someone help me on acheiving the submenu in HTML code?

Tried several modifications to HTML and nothing worked.

Home

Kubernetes

- Kubernetes Config
- Kubectl Commands
- Kubernetes Security